# How can I split the app bundle in vite / rollup to separate public and private routes?

Tags: reactjs, express, vite, rollupjs

Basically I need to build two bundles: one with all the public routes of the app and another with private routes only accessible after user authenticates.

When a user tries to access any of the routes  they will hit an express server that will verify the user and load the correct bundle, something like this :

```
app.use('/files/public_bundle.js', (req, res) => {
    // send the bundle
})

app.use('/files/private_bundle.js', /* JWT middleware */, (req, res) => {
    // send the bundle
})
```

How can I do this with vite ?